# Angular Js calling method of one page from another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Is there any way by which i can make one function present on a page to be called and execute on success of any event from other page linked by custom directive on that page ??

Scenario : I have a page with grid having different columns, alongwith one custom directive by which i am editing data by opening modal popup particular to that row, now i want to call one method on parent page which will validate the new values if incorrect the final 'Submit' button will be disabled else automatically enabled.

I would be thankful for the help, i tired passing method to custom directive but it didn't worked.

Comment: your code please

Comment: It seems like you want an output binding on the directive - you define the function in the parent page, but call it from the directive. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive (ctrl+f for '&')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give a shot to `$emit` and `$broadcast` services:

**$emit**

It dispatches an event name upwards through the scope hierarchy and notify to the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners. The event life cycle starts at the scope on which $emit was called. The event traverses upwards toward the root scope and calls all registered listeners along the way. The event will stop propagating if one of the listeners cancels it.

**$broadcast**

It dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes (and their children) and notify to the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners. The event life cycle starts at the scope on which $broadcast was called. All listeners for the event on this scope get notified. Afterwards, the event traverses downwards toward the child scopes and calls all registered listeners along the way. The event cannot be canceled.

**$on**

It listen on events of a given type. It can catch the event dispatched by $broadcast and $emit.

---

Demo working code, visually showing scope tree (parent/child relationship):
  http://plnkr.co/edit/0kUXvoRkPPNJpQ2C2xWU?p=preview